# How to define common field types in Solr for all cores?

Tags: solr, solr-schema

Lets assume that I have a Solr instance with a few cores that use different languages. For example, I have five different cores: two of them use English, two of them use German, and one uses French.

At present each core has its own field types definitions defined in schema.xml.

I would like to store my field types definitions in one place (within the same Solr instance) in order to be able to share them between cores.

Is it possible? And if so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

use Solrcloud. Then, you common fields live in a *configset* you upload to zookeeper, and you use the same config to create N different collections. Then all share the same types

Comment: This [also works for non-cloud cores](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/config-sets.html#config-sets). And it was my understanding that configsets are only read when the collection or core is created, since a collection or core can modify its schema after that without it being reflected in the configset?

Comment: true, I never used this outside solrcloud so I don't know how it works. I don't understand your second sentence

Comment: My point is that if a configset is modified is the change present in all collections that uses that configset at the time, or is the configuration local to the collection and copied from the configset when the collection is created?

Comment: not sure in the standalon mode, in solrcloud, if you modify a configset, any collection that was created with it will get updated to latest one upon reload/restart